# integrate smartmenus with laravel

Tags: laravel, smartmenus

Im new in Laravel and I try to integrate smartmenus [smartmenus](https://www.smartmenus.org/) with laravel via npm

This is what i have in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "npm": "^6.8.0",
    "smartmenus": "^1.1.0",
    "smartmenus-bootstrap-4": "^0.1.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.2.6"
}
```

app.js

```
require('smartmenus');
```

and in the .vue file

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="sm sm-blue">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2-3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>

...
mounted(){
        this.listarClientes();
        $('#main-menu').smartmenus();
    }
```

I dont know what I miss and if it is the correct way to do

Thanks

Comment: What exactly happened ? What error message was produced ?

Comment: There is no error, it does not do anything